# Is there any development tool for sending sms from my computer to mobile phones?

Tags: mobile, sms, gsm

I want to develop an interface in my computer that will send sms from a text box to the computer attached phone(which has gsm based SIM) and phone will deliver that sms to a particular number(the number will also be given in text field).
I want to know what are the tools i may use for this purpose.What programming languages will be better for this kind of job?(java/.net/php/UNIX shell script).

Answer (score 1):

Somewhat different in terms of use, but the following question probably can get you started with some of the research:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/238579/free-sms-api

Answer (score 1):

You could download a program called [gnokii](http://www.gnokii.org/) (I think it works both on Linux and Windows, please check the website). You can connect a very cheap Nokia mobile phone (check the list that are compatible) and send instructions to the cell phone using this program, like sending sms.

I did this some years ago with a very cheap Nokia phone. Of course I had to pay for each SMS sent, but this depends on the plan of your operator.. in my case I bought a SMS packpage for 6 bucks, then I could send 120 SMS (I'm from Brazil, check your location).